# DataTemplate из DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-шаблоны

В общем обращаюсь к темплейту внутри этого же темплейта - Exception

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="r_ReadOnlyObjectProperty">
  ...
  <!-- ТУТ -->
  <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=r_ReadOnlyObjectProperty}" ItemsSource="...">
    ...
  </ItemsControl>
  ...
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Хм. А не будет ли у вас переполнение стека, раз внутри темплейта разворачивается такой же темплейт (и так будет по идее до бесконечности в глубину).

Comment: В моём случае нет, хотя я допускают такую возможность в будущем. В данном случае тепмплейт не видит сам себя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ нашел [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299915/are-recursive-datatemplates-possible)

Вместо `{StaticResource ResourceKey=r_ReadOnlyObjectProperty}` используем `{DynamicResource ResourceKey=r_ReadOnlyObjectProperty}`